# NSurlconncetion received data length always 0 but file saving works

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hi i want to show the received bytes in the console.

```
  (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
 [receivedData appendData:data];
 NSNumber *resourceLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[receivedData length]];
    NSLog(@"resourceData length: %d ", [resourceLength intValue]);
 if (file)  { 
        [file seekToEndOfFile];
    } 
 [file writeData:data]; 
}
```

the file successfully downloads and safed it into docoument dir but the nslog show always 
resourceData length: 0

receivedata is NSMutableData *receivedData; in the .h file

the strange thing is that the exceptedbytes work well. here the code for that:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection )connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse)response {
 localFilename = [[[url2 absoluteString] lastPathComponent] copy];
 NSLog(localFilename); 
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0] ; 
    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:localFilename]; 
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:appFile contents:nil attributes:nil];
```

expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
 NSLog(@"content-length: %lli Bytes", expectedBytes);
 file = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:appFile] retain];

if (file)   {

```
    [file seekToEndOfFile];
}
```

}

can somebody help me. i really dont know what i am doing wrong

kind regards

tammo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you allocated and initialised `receivedData`? One usually does

```
receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
```

right after creating an `NSURLConnection` instance, and then

```
[receivedData setLength:0];
```

upon receiving a response via `-connection:didReceiveResponse:`, and

```
[receivedData appendData:data];
```

upon receiving data via `-connection:didReceiveData:`. This is exemplified in the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE). If you haven’t instantiated `receivedData`, it is probably `nil` and `[receivedData length]` returns 0 in that case.